# Sorting odd numbers at the beginning of array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to sort odd numbers at the beginning of the array.
For example:

`myArray[8] = {6,3,8,9,6,0,4,7};`

**>> Output: "3   9   7"**

Which type of algorithm should I follow?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We can help you with coding problems. However, we are not a code writing or homework service. You should at least have tried something yourself...

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition):

```
int myArray[] = {6, 3, 8, 9, 6, 0, 4, 7};
const auto first = std::begin(myArray);
const auto last = std::stable_partition(
    std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), [](int x) { return x % 2; });
```

Then the range `[first, last)` will represent the elements you want.